# Menu contextual

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm trying to make a context menu to edit and delete items from a list. As follows.

HTML

```
<div class="row">
        <div id="capa1" class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
            <p> Div 1</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div id="capa2" class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
            <p> Div 2</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div id="capa3" class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
            <p> Div 3</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is the contextual menu

```
    <ul id="menuCapa" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1"> 


    <li role="presentation">
        <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#" onClick="restauraCapa();">Restaurar</a>
    </li> 
    <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
    <li role="presentation">
        <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#" onClick="eliminaCapa();">Eliminar</a>
    </li>

</ul>
```

And the script

```
    <script>


    //cierra cuando abandona el elemento
    $(document).mouseleave(function(){
         $("#menuCapa").hide('fast');
    });

    //cierra cuando se presiona esc
    $(document).keydown(function(){
         $("#menuCapa").hide('fast');
    });



    //muestra el menu
    $("#capa1").mousedown(function(e) { 
    if (e.button == 2){            
    $("#menuCapa").css("top", e.pageY - 20);
    $("#menuCapa").css("left", e.pageX - 20);
    $("#menuCapa").show('fast');    
    }
    });




    //cierra el menu por defecto
    $(document).bind("contextmenu", function(e){ 
    return false;
    });



</script>
```

The menu works but for a single id, since the div I generate them through a foreach cycle with php that is to say they are dynamic I need to know which was the id to which was given a click to be able to pass it to the function, I hope that I have explained well and beforehand thank you.

Comment: if you wanna ask in espanyola ask over here... https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: show the php code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give them each the same class

Then

```
$(".capa_class").mousedown(function(e) { 
    if (e.button == 2){            
      $(this).css("top", e.pageY - 20);
      $(this).css("left", e.pageX - 20);
      $(this).show('fast');    
    }
});
```

So the trick is to use a class, not an id, and use $(this) to do whatever you want with the clicked/mouseleave/keydown element.